# words that describe an advertisement (works effectively to attract/lure people to buy the product)

Tags: word-request

What words can be used to describe an advertisement which works very effectively to attract people to buy the product?

I don't think I can say **attractive advertisement** or **luring advertisement** as there isn't any google results for those phrases.

Comment: Could you supply a sentence where this phrase or word would fit? For example, "Company XYZ's advertising campaign proved to be  ____" OR "Product B doesn't attract buyers unlike Product A because it lacks  _____"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few words which are synonyms to attractive and also can be used efficiently with the word advertising. Consider the following options:

1. **catchy**:  *[‘They've come up with all manner of catchy slogans designed to tip the scales in their favour.’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/catchy)*.
2. **alluring**: ‘[Such entertainments offered alluring images of appealing stars surrounded by an abundance of consumer goods.’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/alluring)
3. **tempting**: *[‘Staff can now offer a tempting range of products from well-known names.’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tempting)*
4. **[creative](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/creative)** (though not synonymous with *attractive*, it can be used with advertisements):

Answer (score 0):

Effective and persuasive appear to be commonly used in the ads industry:

[Characteristics of an ***Effective or Persuasive Advertisement***](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/characteristics-effective-persuasive-advertisement-61445.html):

> - Effectiveness and persuasiveness of ads are closely linked. While you often have different goals with ads, the general intent of each is to persuade customers to think, feel or act in a certain way toward your brand. With this in mind, effective, persuasive ads have several common traits.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=persuasive%20advertisement%2C%20effective%20advertisement&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpersuasive%20advertisement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceffective%20advertisement%3B%2Cc0) effective, persuasive advertisement

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try 'how to create advertising that **sells**'?

https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+advertising+that+sells